# gdb cannot find symbols when debug symbols are split into dwo dwarf file

Tags: c++, linux, linker, gdb

I want to build a binary with `g++` and split debug info into a separate file. So-called `DebugFission`.

Let's say you are in a folder. There is a file `src/main.cpp` with trivial content: `int main() {}`

I want to compile it using `-gsplit-dwarf`:

```
mkdir -p obj
(cd obj && g++ -c -g -gsplit-dwarf ../src/main.cpp -o main.o)
g++ -Wl,--gdb-index -fuse-ld=gold  obj/*.o -o main
```

And I want to set a breakpoint in `main` function:

```
gdb main
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40058a: file ../src/main.cpp, line 2.
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, main () at ../src/main.cpp:2
2       ../src/main.cpp: No such file or directory.
```

But `gdb` cannot find symbols. It tries to look for symbols relative to `obj` directory.

Am I missing some arguments?

I use the following versions: `gcc-4.9.3`, `binutils-2.26.1`, `gdb-7.11.1`.

*Some extra info*:

```
readelf -wi main
Contents of the .debug_info section:
...
<20>   DW_AT_GNU_dwo_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x0): main.dwo
<24>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x9): /tmp/blah/obj
<2c>   DW_AT_GNU_dwo_id  : 0xf4f335f2e5c313e0

readelf -wi obj/main.dwo
Contents of the .debug_info.dwo section:
...
<c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indexed string: 0x0): GNU C++ 4.9.3 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -gsplit-dwarf -fstack-protector-strong
<d>   DW_AT_language    : 4 (C++)
<e>   DW_AT_name        : (indexed string: 0x3): ../src/main.cpp
<f>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indexed string: 0x1): /tmp/blah/obj
<10>   DW_AT_GNU_dwo_id  : 0xf4f335f2e5c313e0
...
```

Comment: Update: it works if I replace `g++` with `clang++`. It seems that the problem is somehow related to `gcc`.