# GNU gdb do not debug application built by icc (Intel C compiler) on Linux

Tags: linux, gdb, intel, gnu, icc

I'm trying debug application using GNU gdb that built by icc (Intel C compiler). But gdb not see any line in file (but if I build app using gcc everything fine).
I have never used before icc compiler so maybe I do something wrong. Please help :)

icc - Version 8.0

gdb - GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-90.el6)

OS  - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)

test.c:

```
1  #include<stdio.h>
2
3  int main(int argc, char **argv)
4  {
5          int count = 0;
6          while(1)
7          {
8                  printf("Work In %d \n",count);
9                  count++;
10                  sleep(2);
11          }
12  }
```

Run build: icc -g -inline_debug_info --gsplit-dwarf ./test.c -o test

And when I tryied to break line (8 line for example) in gdb, gdb shows: No line 8 in file "./test.c"

Output:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-90.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /tmp/test...done.

(gdb) break 8

No line 8 in file "./test.c".
```

Comment: What if try to build without `--gsplit-dwarf`, just `icc -g ... ` ? There is potentially similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913199/gdb-cannot-find-symbols-when-debug-symbols-are-split-into-dwo-dwarf-file) where gcc  with split-dwarf didn't work, so might be worth to try.

Comment: I tried: 
icc -g -inline_debug_info ./test.c -o test 
and 
icc -g ./test.c -o test 

Nothing changed. gdb still don't handle the line

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Especially with some blurry background. Please post text as text, into the question. Please post the output of `file ./test` and `objdump -drl ./a.out | grep -C20 '<main>'`. Does `objdump -drl` ouptuts line numbers?

Comment: `file ./test`: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped. `objdump` returned line numbers. Output: 080487e4 <main>: main(): /tmp/./test.c:4 ... 80487f0: 56 push %esi /tmp/./test.c:5 80487f1: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00 movl $0x0,-0x4(%ebp) /tmp/./test.c:6 ... 80487ff: 74 33 je 8048834 <main+0x50> /tmp/./test.c:8 ... 8048812: e8 41 fe ff ff call 8048658 <printf@plt>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971958/gdb-doesnt-find-line-numbers-objdump-does ?

Comment: icc not contains options like -gstab. But I try figure out why my version of icc doesn't have options like [gdwarf](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/output-debug-and-precompiled-header-pch-options/gdwarf.html). If I undestood rihgt we should provide debug info to the gdb by DWARF format

Comment: All the tools you are using are _ancient_ and long past their end-of-life support. Consider using something more recent.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but we can't use another version of compiler unfortunately because customer have enough big old project and can't switch to newest version.

Comment: Do you have the Intel debugger, `idb`?

Answer (score 0):

> Output:

```
080487e4 <main>: main(): /tmp/./test.c:4 ... 
80487f0: 56 push %esi /tmp/./test.c:5
80487f1: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00 movl $0x0,-0x4(%ebp) /tmp/./test.c:6 ...
80487ff: 74 33 je 8048834 <main+0x50> /tmp/./test.c:8 ...
8048812: e8 41 fe ff ff call 8048658 <printf@plt>
```

This *might* be a confusion between `test.c` and `./test.c`.

Does the picture change if you use `icc -g test.c -o test` instead?
(Using `./test.c` is quite unusual and completely unnecessary.)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed. I tried use `break <line_num>` and `break test.c:<line_num>`, but this still not work.